# matrix multiplication on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, matrix, bigdata

I'm looking for the best and easy way of matrix multiplication on hadoop java. Meanwhile I looked at this link http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html but I felt tough to understand it.

Overall: I've two files matrixA(m x n) and matrixB(n x m). I want matrixC(m x m) by multiplying A and B. I'll pass above two files to mapreduce program.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Could you reprocess the matrix two files as:

```
 System.out.println( column + " , " + row + "\t" + value );
```

I am thinking that you can map over both by outputting:

```
context.write( new Text( column + " , " + row ), new IntWritable( value ) );
```

then reduce with an iterator and just multiply the values.

```
for( int val: value ) {
    int result *= val;
}

context.write( key, new IntWritable( result ));
```